# Convert pybind numpy array from float to double in place

Tags: python, c++, numpy, pybind11

For a project I have to pass a numpy of dtype `float` into a pybind function.  That float pybind array then gets passed to a function that accepts a pointer to a double as shown here:

```
// this is the pybind signature
m.def("example", [](py::array_t<float, py::array::c_style> T) { ... }

// this is the cpp signature
void example(double * T) { ... }
```

The cpp function operates on the passed numpy array in place.  Therefore numpy variable passed into the function from Python should be altered.

My problem is that I don't know how to convert the passed numpy array into an array of floats to an array of doubles while also keeping the original reference.  Or at least have the original numpy float array now reference the new double array.

When I use `std::move` the original float pybind array still keeps its size and the new double array has a new address.  Does that mean that `std::move` is actually performing a copy?

My current solution does not follow the guidelines and expects doubles:

```
// this is the pybind signature
m.def("example", [](py::array_t<double, py::array::c_style> T) { 
    namespace::example(T.mutable_data(0));
}
```

Let me know if that's not best practice.

Comment: They occupy different numbers of bytes, so in-place conversion is not possible.

Comment: Thanks @cpaulj.  That's what I thought but wasn't positive that is was not possible.  Is there a way for the original array passed in to reference the new double array?  So that the Python variable passed in is now referencing a new numpy array that is of dtype double?